# php insert data after a period of time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Currently I have an application whereby when the user click the submit button, it will trigger the `insert` code to insert the record for `reports` function.

The problem I'm facing now is, the user not a computer savvy, therefore I've an inaccurate data from the table. Below are the few examples that cause the data capture incorrectly.

Case 1: Once the user click the submit button, the data already `insert` to the database but the user accidentally hits the **submit** button again and the `insert` trigger again and causing the database has two same records with a different timestamp in about 5 to 10sec.

Case 2: The first record user enter is actually not the user wants, for example, the user wants to key-in `29/10/2013` but the user key-in as `28/10/2013` and the user again hit the back button and insert the correct one which is `29/10/2013` and a single transaction it have 2 record which is one is the correct date and one is the mistake date.

Below are the code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO log (dob, log_datetime, log_count, amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $userDate);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $now, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $cust_count);
$stmt->bindParam(4, $amount);

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$cust_count = 1;
$amount = 10;
$stmt->execute();
```

The code above trigger whenever the user hits the submit button, so I was thinking is there possible to make the `insert` code to trigger after a period of time, example `30sec`?

**Additional Notes**

1. This is an application developed and execute the database from the table
2. It has nothing to do with form validation, as I already coded the form validation part.
3. My question is **is there any way to trigger the `insert` query on specific amount of time set**

I search in SO and Google, but I couldn't find a relevant example to work with.

Please suggest me any method that can fix the above two case scenarios.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the first case, disable the button when the form is submited.
For the second case, [validate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation) the date before inserting it into the database.

Comment: maybe you didn't get me clear, is not the form validation part. My database store date from 01/01/1940 till 01/01/2021 and the user need to key in each date to extract the data they want. It's an app, and I no need to explain further more on the function. Now my question is storing the data to mysql is there anyway to make the `insert` code trigger on specific amount of time eg: 30sec and so on?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/sleep

> sleep(30);
>
> $stmt->execute();

Will do what you want I believe.

Comment: something like this, but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have that behavior. I think that what you are looking for is an asynchronous task queue, like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to catch all UI leaks can prove difficult and cumbersome.

I would rather use the timestamp in the DB as a temporal filter

I would query the most recent records (in the last 30 seconds) using cust_count as a candidate key, and update the last record (if any) instead of creating it anew.

Schematic example:

```
function update_log ($entry)
{
    $recent = $db->select (
          "id FROM log 
          WHERE timestamp > now()-30 seconds
          AND   user = $entry->user");
    if ($recent)
    {
        // overwrite last record with current entry (and refresh timestamp)
    }
    else
    {
       // create a new entry
    }
}
```

You could even delete all logs of the user adding an entry that are newer than 30 seconds.

Comment: mind to show some example? I couldn't figure out what you say.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the submit button upon submitting, and on the post-submission page, show the user the submitted data and give them a clear way to edit it.

Users generally suspect that hitting back into a form is not a good idea, but you're not giving them any better options.

Comment: I am trying to make a less complicated approach for the non computer savvy, my approach is simple, input data page -> submit -> result page. As I mention, they are non computer savvy, sometimes they might hit the wrong number on the number pad and when the results show wrong date instead the date they want, they will hit the back button to enter the correct date.